# How to use LIMIT with SQLiteDatabase.query()?

Tags: android

What's the syntax for using a LIMIT clause with SQLiteDatabase.query()?:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String), java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

is it:

1. "N"
2. "LIMIT N"
3. other?

the docs don't say, and other posts are confusing on the subject.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIMIT is append by Android. So it will be `N` or `N, K` if you need.